# Make a Windows form automatically take the size of it's child table layout panel

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a windows form that contains a table layout panel extending the whole form, the size of this table layout panel may change at run time according to it's content, how can I make it's parent form automatically take its size,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set property `TableLayoutPanel.Dock` as `Fill` and change `YourForm.Size` property according to `TableLayoutPanel` content